# Emacs CC-Mode Indent c-block-comment-ender Differently

Tags: c++, c, emacs, indentation

TL;DR:
I want emacs to indent C block comments like this:

```
/*
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
  Sit Amet
*/
```

Not this:

```
/*
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
  Sit Amet
  */
```

What do?

---

I have the following as part of my `cc-mode` style:

```lisp
(c-add-style
  "jf-cc-mode-style"
  '(
     (c-tab-always-indent        . t)
     (c-comment-only-line-offset . 0)
     (c-offsets-alist . (
       (c             . 2)
       (comment-intro . 0)
     )
   )
```

But I have not been able to find anything in [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Multi_002dLine-Comments) about being able to set the indentation for the comment end (`*/`) to something different. Changing the value of `c` does of course change it, but this also affects the middle lines too.

---

Follow up:
Can I also have it indent specific non-empty comment-ends to column 0?

```
/*
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
  Sit Amet
M*/
// or
/*
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
  Sit Amet
C*/
```

not

```
/*
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
  Sit Amet
  M*/
// or
/*
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
  Sit Amet
  C*/
```

I suppose I can advise [`c-lineup-C-comments`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Comment-Line_002dUp) to also match a regexp, but maybe there's a cleaner way?

Comment: Please don't post the same question to StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Choose one to keep and please delete the other. Thx.

Comment: Get rid of the `(c . 2)` line. Don't forget to `M-x c-set-style` afterwards (I'm not sure whether it's necessary or not, but better safe than sorry).

Comment: Removing `(c . 2)` works thanks (I already had the `c-set-style`, the snippet above is just a subset of the full style)! On a side note, is it possible to get it to align the comment-ender to column 0 even if isn't empty (i.e. just `*/`)? Can just match a simple regex, I'll update the post to elaborate.